# How does one harvest aloe vera leaves?

Tags: harvesting, raised-beds, technique, succulents, aloe

I grow a few large [*Aloe vera*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloe_vera) plants which I'm interested in harvesting regularly during the summer months.

- What percentage of the foliage should be removed at each harvest for highest production?
- How much regrowth should I wait for between harvesting?

Comment: Would you please clarify if you're referring to harvesting the oil from the Aloe plant, or harvesting in the sense of pruning in order to best grow a long-lasting, healthy plant? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to remove only the outer leaves, as they are the oldest and contain the most gel. As for regrowth, I would wait until the next set of leaves are well established before removing another set.

Source: http://www.wikihow.com/Trim-an-Aloe-Vera-Plant

Comment: How many leaves is a set?

Comment: A set, to me, would be the next ring of leaves around the interior of the plant.